# Probability of a never ending experiment

Tags: probability

This question (may be even mathematically stupid to ask) on probability needs a little bit of background on doubly linked list data-structure which you can read [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Assume a linked list with finite odd number of nodes (more than 1 nodes) and the address of the middle node is given. You decide to do an experiment.

1. Flip a coin.
2. Say on **head** you traverse one node towards left, on **tail** you move one node right.

What is the probability that you will never reach the any end of the linked list. (You can assume number of nodes in list as `2n + 1` if it makes the answer more readable)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the probability is zero. You can show this with a Markov chain model and a banded transition matrix.

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard exercise in Bernoulli random walks. However, your case is covered by the first few pages of these notes: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap20.pdf

Comment: @Glen_b I had a hunch that it will be zero, but the chapter proves it. Thanks!

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem implies that after $N\gg n^2$ flips, the chance of currently being beyond an end is very close to $1-2n/\sqrt{2\pi N},$ which is nearly certain.  *A fortiori,* the chance of never having reached an end is at least as great.  BTW, you don't need to know anything about doubly-linked lists: the question can be couched in terms of the difference between the counts of heads and tails observed.

Answer (score 0):

To show the probability is zero:

Consider the leftmost node $N$ that is

> visited infinitely often with positive probability.

Then, the conditional probability that

> the node to the left of it is *not* visited infinitely often,

is zero.

Comment: I understood the proof for the probability being zero, but wanted to see your perspective of the problem. Can you elaborate?